# Zapier oauth is giving me 401 error invalid client id

Tags: oauth-2.0, zapier

Hi I am trying to connect to zapier using oauth v2
when testing the connection it's success.

but when i create the action it's giving me invalid client_id error 401

> Error from halted execution: What happened (You are seeing this because you are an admin): Starting POST request to https://api-oclass-uat.oas.asia/o/token/ Received 401 code from https://api-oclass-uat.oas.asia/o/token/ after 876ms Received content "{"error": "invalid_client"}" Console logs: Stack trace: RefreshAuthError at throwForStaleAuth (/var/task/node_modules/zapier-platform-core/src/http-middlewares/after/throw-for-stale-auth.js:10:11) at Object. (/var/task/node_modules/zapier-platform-core/src/middleware.js:80:37) at bound (node:domain:433:15) at Object.runBound (node:domain:444:12) at Object.tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23) at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31) at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18) at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10) at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18) at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12) at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9) at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5) at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14) at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21) at process.topLevelDomainCallback (node:domain:161:15) at process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:24)